# Prolog for loop syntax error

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, swi-prolog, b-prolog

I am trying to make a game similar to minesweeper and i need to check the neighbours of a square in the map but i get a syntax error at my for loop, I am using SWI-Prolog

```
checkneighbours(X,Y) :-
retractall(vecini(_)),
assert(vecini(0)),
foreach(I in X-1..X+1,
            (foreach J in Y-1..Y+1,
                (map(I,J,Z),
                    ( Z=:= "X"
                                -> vecini(V),
                                V1 is V+1,
                                assert(vecini(V1))
                    )
                )
            )
        ).
```

didn't I declare the loops right? or how can I loop between X-1 and X+1?

Comment: So what error are you seeing?

Comment: Syntax error at first foreach

Comment: Just add the exact error output to the question. And where did you see this `I in X-1..X+1` syntax?

Comment: I saw the syntax in a prolog example on the net, i don't think it was for SWI-Prolog, I found that for loops the syntax is like this: 
`"?- foreach(between(1,4,X), dif(X,Y)), Y = 5."`
so how should i rewrite the loop?

Comment: This is about B-Prolog's loops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no real loops like that in Prolog. I am also not sure if it is wise to use `assert` to dynamically change the fact database (it is usually better to represent your data in a structure). But if you really insist to use a "loop" for its side effects, you should be using `forall`:

```
?- forall( between(-1,1,X), format('~d~n', [X]) ).
-1
0
1
true.
```

Comment: I tried this "forall( between(X-1,X+1,I), format('~d~n', [I]) )" but if i give the value 6 I get this error: ERROR: between/3: Type error: `integer' expected, found `6-1'

Comment: Yes, you first need to evaluate the integer expression `6-1` (or `X-1`) to an integer using `is/2`; then you can stick it into `between/3`. Altogether, this is why I said that there are no real loops in Prolog, it is not meant to be used in this way and accordingly, you need to write more.